# Magento shopping cart only for logged in users

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart

I am looking for a great solution for the following issue. I would like hide the shopping cart from those users which are not logged in to our site www.thebodyshop.ie
The site is currently not e-commerce yet and I am planning to test out with the above. Please advice any solutions which could help me to create visible shopping cart for logged in(registered) users only.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [Magento Hide Price Extension](http://www.magikcommerce.com/magento-hide-price-extension)

It will allow you to hide add to cart button & price from non logged in users. 
Following options are provided with this extension:

**1.Hide Price & Add to Cart button -** If admin has set the option to hide prices only for guest or visitors then product price is hidden on store’s front end and a pre defined message is displayed. (Ex. You need to be logged in to see the price!). Only logged in customers can see the prices in this particular case.

**2.Call For Price -** If admin has setup “Call for price” option then all guests, visitors or even customers will not be able to see the product price or add to cart button, instead they will see store’s phone number to inquire about the price OR Hide Price Magento extension also creates a link on store’ front-end, when customer click’s on this link a form comes which sends an email to admin about the price request. Admin can setup the email addresses which get notified when price request is done by customer. Admin have ability to enable or displable the customer notification for his/her request.

**3.Inquiry Form -** If admin has setup “Inquire” option then all guests, visitors or even customers will keep showing the product prices but will disable/remove/hide add to cart button for everyone. For safety reasons some products may not be sold online so they can be shown with the prices but instead of showing add to cart you can display an inquiry form link, which will show a popup with contact details of store owner or with a form to be filled by the customer to inquire about the product which sends an email to admin. Admin can setup the email addresses which get notified when Inquiry request is done by customer. Admin have ability to enable or displable the customer notification for his/her request.

Comment: Is this extension is works only for hide price option? I need to keep the price visible for all the time, however the shopping cart need to be visible only for logged in users.

Comment: Please check updated post above with detailed features

Comment: Thanks for your respond to me. The point 3.Inquiry Form could work for me. Thank You! I hope there will be more suggestion so I will be able to choose the best solution for this issue.